# Ubuntu freezes randomly during heavy disk i/o

Tags: lenovo, performance

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 but had this problem on 17.04 (from which I upgraded to 17.10). My system tends to freeze when there is heavy disk i/o, for instance, if we're running up docker containers and opening a large file (PDF for example).

Other than that I'm quite happy developing on 17.10. I'm running on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon with an SSD (I have a weekly cron job for FSTrim) and 8GB memory.

It might be worth mentioning that I originally had 2/3 freezes per day, but tracked that down to having no swap file. Adding that seems to have dramatically improved things.

The swap file is 8GB, as I have 8GB of RAM.

Also, my home dir is encrypted, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Also, when the freezes occur they often 'unglue' in five min or so. So , seems like a disk bottle neck?

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce this issue with synthetic disc benchmarks to gather more information, e. g. `stress -d 4` for something very simple? Thanks.

Comment: May you should time limit the stress command:  `stress -d 4 -t 45` for a 45 second command

Comment: Read `man journalctl` and use the `--since=` and `--until=` switches to look at the logs covering the issue.